# The number of elements in ICollection is zero in many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a database made with Entity Framework. I have two tables Users and Advertisments and the relationship between them is Many-to-Many. Everything is working fine except when I want to return the number of ICollection in class Users.

```
[Table("Advertisments")]
public class Advertisment
{
    public Advertisment()
    {
        Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int AdvertismentID { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public double Rating { get; set; }

    public int NumberOfRates { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    public double Longitude { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

}
[Table("Users")]
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        FavouriteAdvertisments = new HashSet<Advertisment>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Advertisment> FavouriteAdvertisments { get; set; }

}

public class GetHiredDBContext : DbContext
{
    public GetHiredDBContext()
        : base("GetHiredDBContext")
    { }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Advertisment> Advertisments { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(a => a.FavouriteAdvertisments).WithMany(u => u.Users).Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("UserID");
                m.MapRightKey("AdvertismentID");
                m.ToTable("UserAdvertisment");
            });
    }
}
```

And this is what I want to do:

```
public ICollection<Advertisment> favouriteAdvertismentsByUser(int UserID)
    {
        GetHiredDBContext db = new GetHiredDBContext();
        foreach (User user in db.Users)
        {
            if (user.UserID == UserID)
            {
                return user.FavouriteAdvertisments;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**Everytime I call this method, the number of elements in ICollection  for every user is 0!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ICollection<Advertisment> favouriteAdvertismentsByUser(int UserID)
{
    GetHiredDBContext db = new GetHiredDBContext();

    // First of all, you probably forgot to "include" FavouriteAdvertisments
    var users = db.Users.Include(u => u.FavouriteAdvertisments);

    // Second of all, use linq!
    return users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserID == UserID).FavouriteAdvertisments;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using Entity Framework you need to write your queries in Linq so the query provider can translate that into a SQL statement. As you have it now it is doing a table scan. Instead try this:

```
public ICollection<Advertisment> favouriteAdvertismentsByUser(int UserID)
{
    return new GetHiredDbContext()
        .Users
        .Single(u => u.UserID = UserID)
        .FavouriteAdvertisements;
}
```

One thing to note, this method now expects there to be exactly 1 record in your table with that `UserID`. It will throw an exception if it does not exist. Personally I prefer this because if I'm calling a method I expect it to work, and exception would mean I coded something wrong allowing me to find bugs earlier. You also do not have to check if your collection is null before getting the count.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it still doesn't work. The length of FavouriteAdvertisments says that is 0

Comment: @АлександарМихајловски Check your data source. Make sure there are records. Also make sure your using the `.Count()` extension for IQueryable instead of the `.Count` property of `ICollection`

Answer (score 0):

The way your entites are currently set up, you will have to either use `Eager`, or `Explicit` loading, your related entites will not be loaded automatically.

To Explicitly load, I believe you can use your original query (provided you're passing an entity that can be found in the DBSet, and make an explicit call to load the related information (using `Load`):

E.g. (provided your entity can be found).

```
public ICollection<Advertisment> favouriteAdvertismentsByUser(User userEntity)
{
    // Load the blog related to a given post
    GetHiredDBContext db = new GetHiredDBContext();

    db.Entry(userEntity).Reference(p => p.FavouriteAdvertisments).Load();

    return user.FavouriteAdvertisments;
}
```

Although it's probably cleaner to obtain your entity from your context, and call load on that, rather than interating through your entire set.

To Eagerly load, you make your load request at the time of query, using `Include`:

```
public ICollection<Advertisment> favouriteAdvertismentsByUser(int userID)
{
    GetHiredDBContext db = new GetHiredDBContext();

    User myUser = db.Users
                    .Where(x => x.UserID = userID)
                    .Include(x => x.FavouriteAdvertisments)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

    return myUser.FavouriteAdvertisments;
}
```

To obtain the data the third way, using `Lazy-Loading`, you would have to make some alterations to your classes, namely marking your `ICollection` navigation properties as virtual, so entity framework is able to create valid proxy types for your classes. Your data would be available as required, and loaded on demand.

Hopefully I haven't got the problem completely wrong, just about to shut down/sleep.

Good luck.

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx